# Clearing a text field on button click

Tags: html

I have two text labels:

```
<div>           
    <input type="text" id="textfield1" size="5"/>
</div>

<div>          
    <input type="text" id="textfield2" size="5"/>           
</div>
```

I would like to have a button called "Clear" that would erase both these fields.

To my knowledge, I know that to implement a button I should use a code like this:

```
<div>      
    <input type="button" value="Clear Fields" onclick=SOMETHING />
</div>
```

Any clues on how to implement `SOMETHING`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

How about just a simple reset button?

```
<form>

  <input type="text" id="textfield1" size="5">
  <input type="text" id="textfield2" size="5">

  <input type="reset" value="Reset">

</form>
```

Answer (score 38):

A simple JavaScript function will do the job.

```
function ClearFields() {

     document.getElementById("textfield1").value = "";
     document.getElementById("textfield2").value = "";
}
```

And just have your button call it:

```
<button type="button" onclick="ClearFields();">Clear</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! , I used this approach but had to do some tweaks , instead of `document.getElementById("textfield1").value = "";` I used `textfield1.value = "";`

Answer (score 10):

If you want to reset it, then simple use:

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset" />
```

But beware, **it will not clear out textboxes that have default `value`**. For example, if we have the following textboxes and by default, they have the following values:

```
<input id="textfield1" type="text" value="sample value 1" />
<input id="textfield2" type="text" value="sample value 2" />
```

So, to clear it out, compliment it with javascript:

```
function clearText()  
{
    document.getElementById('textfield1').value = "";
    document.getElementById('textfield2').value = "";
}
```

And attach it to `onclick` of the reset button:
`<input type="reset" value="Reset" onclick="clearText()" />`

Comment: <input id="textfield1" type="text" />
<input id="textfield2" type="text" />
For better Clarity, Dear  @Lynnell Emmanuel Neri, Would you please include above two lines too in Answer.?

Comment: Thank you @Arun I have just edited the answer to reflect your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will add a button and let you use it to clear the values

```
<div>           
<input type="text" id="textfield1" size="5"/>         
</div>

<div>          
<input type="text" id="textfield2" size="5"/>           
</div>

<div>
    <input type="button" onclick="clearFields()" value="Clear">
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function clearFields() {
    document.getElementById("textfield1").value=""
    document.getElementById("textfield2").value=""
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to "Submit and Reset" the the "form" with one Button click, Try this!

Here I have used jQuery function, it can be done by simple JavaScript also...

```
        <form id="form_data">
           <input type="anything"  name="anything" />
           <input type="anything"  name="anything" />

             <!-- Save and Reset button -->
           <button type="button" id="btn_submit">Save</button>
           <button type="reset" id="btn_reset" style="display: none;"></button>
        </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#btn_submit').click(function(){
        // Do what ever you want
       $('#btn_reset').click();  // Clicking reset button
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same task when working with my todo app, but I have to do it when clicking on Enter key, I did the snippet code below and it worked for me

```js
const todosArr = [];

function addsNewTodo(){
    const inputFeild = document.getElementById('todo-title');
    todosArr.push(inputFeild.value);
    
    // I'm using keycode for Enter key
    // this will check if the user presses on Enter key
    // then it'll clear the input field ( inputFeil.value )
    
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        inputFeild.value = ""
    }
}

function render() {
    // this makes sure to add one todo list at a time
    // try to delete it and add two todos and see what happens 
    document.getElementById('todo-list').innerHTML = ''

    todosArr.forEach(function (todoTitle){
    const element = document.createElement('lable')
    element.innerText= todoTitle;
    const todoList = document.getElementById('todo-list');
    todoList.appendChild(element);
});
}


function all() {
document.getElementById('todo-title').addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13){
        addsNewTodo()
        render()
    }
}) 
}

all()
```

```css
lable {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<input id="todo-title" type="text" />
<div id="todo-list"></div>
```

you can read more on KeyboardEvent Value [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/#aa-keycode-values)