# Cannot clear text input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've tried several different ways, including Pure-JS and jQuery, but I can't get my input text field to clear. Please help.

Here's the relevant HTML:

```
<div align="center" id="searchDiv"></div>
<input type="text" id="searchBar" size="40" onsubmit="loadAllItems()">
<input type="submit" id="searchButton" value="Search" onclick="loadAllItems()">
<input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="reset()">
```

I'm trying to submit the searchBar, run backend code, and then call the reset() function to avoid manually clearing the text field:

```
function reset() {
        document.getElementById("gradeQuestionsForm").reset();
        document.getElementById('Output1').innerHTML = '';
        document.getElementById('Output1').innerHTML = '';
        updateStatus('Form has been reset.');
      }
```

I tested with a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GandalfTheWhite/pr7u58af/11/). Please advise.

Comment: Duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14837466/clearing-a-text-field-on-button-click

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700471/set-value-of-input-using-javascript-function

Comment: [working here](https://jsfiddle.net/pr7u58af/12/)

Comment: If you've tried several different ways, please share so we can better help you.

Comment: wrap all the input fields in `<form>` tag and then set reset button type to reset as ` type="reset"`. It is default functionality of reset button and no need to write javascript function.

Comment: Thank you to those who read all of my question, especially miglio, who provided a solution. I read the other questions first, but they did not address my concern directly. It works now with `$('#searchBar').val('');` (I didn't have the ' around #searchBar when I tried the jquery before.)

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery you can do like this

 [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/txe8qg0w/)

```
$('#searchBar').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `document.getElementById("searchBar").value = '';`

Also, you need to set `LOAD TYPE` TO `No wrap -in <head>` in your JSFiddle

[image].

See more on running script on JSFiddle [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468350/javascript-not-running-on-jsfiddle-net).

Comment: Thanks for the help with JSFiddle. I feel like I'm in Coding Kindergarten: learning shapes and colors.