# How to clear input field with ajax

Tags: javascript

How can I reset (clear) my input field on success?

```
<input id="tagtitle" class="form-control" name="tagtitle" type="text">
```

I have tried:

```
$('#tagtitle').empty();
```

and

```
document.getElementById("tagtitle").reset();
```

none of them works.

## Screen capture

*this site doesn't allow to upload videos so i had to use this way or link you to another website.*

```html
<div style="width:100%;height:0px;position:relative;padding-bottom:72.283%;"><iframe src="https://streamable.com/s/avie6/njsnuh" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;overflow:hidden;"></iframe></div>
```

Comment: Where is the input field in the example?

Comment: wait, you expect us to watch a video that is in ah html code block? Show your actual HTML! not a video of I am guessing HTML

Comment: @epascarello updated, video is 5sec just to know what i mean, if you don't want don't watch it, nobody forced you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14837466/clearing-a-text-field-on-button-click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input fields' values can be reset by assigning to their `.value` property:

```
document.getElementById("tagtitle").value = '';
```

The same is true for `textarea`s.

If you want to do it with jQuery:

```
$('#tagtitle').val('');
```

Comment: thank you, please wait 9min till i'm allowed to accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("tagtitle").value = "";
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value

Answer (score 0):

If your project has jquery, use `$('#tagtitle').val('');` is the easiest way unless you would refresh your page after the ajax request.